linux ssh command with password (one liner)
Is it possible to run ssh command and also pass the password as a string, all in one line?
I have tried:
echo "password" | ssh -tt user@server

But it didnt work.

Have you try to use ssh keys?

The problem with your approach is that the pipe ties up ssh to read standard input from the pipe, so it immediately exits without doing anything usefl.

@tripleee do you think its possible to hold the "password" in some other way and pass it to the ssh interactive prompt?

The duplicate shows you that and much more. Going forward, please search before asking.

@RomeoNinov yes, i know how to establish successful ssh connection by using keys. I also know about the sshpass. But, I want to know if there is a way to use the native ssh service and connect instantly to a remote server by passing the password in the same command.

@scaleTillDust, using keys you use only native ssh and options this tool offer.

Running it this way would quite likely result in the password being held in the history file. That is just a massive security no-no.

You can use sshpass to connect with a password, but I would keep in mind that anyone who gains access to the terminal could theoretically look up the previous command and find the password in plain text.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/
sshpass -p "password" ssh username@server
If you just need to log in without needing to type into the console then you could look into using public key authentication.  This allows you to just ssh into the server without needing to specify the username or password as long as you have the trusted keys set up.
https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/public-key-authentication
https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews
